LSTM model deployment in AWS Sagemaker
Please consider that I am new to AWS Sagemaker before answering this post please. Thanks in advance.
I have trained LSTM model on some data to make predictions. I want to deploy it by creating an endpoint on AWS Sagemaker t make batch predictions. The model is trying to predict if the output is 0 or 1 (binary classification on timeseries data). The trained model is in the format of .keras
Every time I try to use this model to deploy, I get a error. The error says that .keras is not the expected type and the model needs to be in the format of .tar.gz
So I tried to re-train the model in the required format and tried to create an endpoint using the below piece of code.
Code used to create an endpoint
And I am getting this error since then. I have tried using few other instance types but no luck. Error message
Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Did you take a look at the logs in CloudWatch? They may provide more details on the issue.
